# Configure network MTU in Openstack with Heat

Tags: openstack, openstack-heat

Is it possible to configure the mtu of a network while creating it with a heat template in Openstack?

I can set the mtu through the CLI `openstack network --mtu <value> <network_id>`

I see a reference to mtu in the heat guide but it doesn't appear to allow setting of the value.

Comment: What is the MTU value you're trying to set?

Comment: Any value. Just want to be able to set it by heat.

Comment: Set it to 1500 to start with and later you can try with 9000 (Jumbo Frames). Test if these values are working for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to set the MTU with heat-templates. You have to use the `value_specs`-field, which allows you additional properties. See its really bad documentation here:

https://docs.openstack.org/heat/pike/template_guide/openstack.html#OS::Neutron::Subnet-prop-value_specs

I tested it with the following simple heat-template:

```
heat_template_version: 2013-05-23
description: tests network

resources:
  demo-network:
    type: OS::Neutron::Net
    properties:
      name: demo-network
      value_specs: { mtu: 1400 }
```

It really created a network with an MTU of 1400 like set in the template. Checked it with a show-command:

```
root@test-node:~# openstack network show demo-network
+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Field                     | Value                                                                                                                                                            |
+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| admin_state_up            | UP                                                                                                                                                               |
| availability_zone_hints   |                                                                                                                                                                  |
| availability_zones        |                                                                                                                                                                  |
| created_at                | 2020-05-16T13:33:53Z                                                                                                                                             |
| description               |                                                                                                                                                                  |
| dns_domain                | None                                                                                                                                                             |
| id                        | 965d890f-0c37-400e-8ee0-ec6ce1fcf4e6                                                                                                                             |
| ipv4_address_scope        | None                                                                                                                                                             |
| ipv6_address_scope        | None                                                                                                                                                             |
| is_default                | None                                                                                                                                                             |
| is_vlan_transparent       | None                                                                                                                                                             |
| location                  | cloud='', project.domain_id=, project.domain_name='Default', project.id='2dacaa8f6d3348f28e126b371bf1dfab', project.name='admin', region_name='RegionOne', zone= |
| mtu                       | 1400                                                                                                                                                             |
| name                      | demo-network                                                                                                                                                     |
| port_security_enabled     | True                                                                                                                                                             |
| project_id                | 2dacaa8f6d3348f28e126b371bf1dfab                                                                                                                                 |
| provider:network_type     | vxlan                                                                                                                                                            |
| provider:physical_network | None                                                                                                                                                             |
| provider:segmentation_id  | 60                                                                                                                                                               |
| qos_policy_id             | None                                                                                                                                                             |
| revision_number           | 1                                                                                                                                                                |
| router:external           | Internal                                                                                                                                                         |
| segments                  | None                                                                                                                                                             |
| shared                    | False                                                                                                                                                            |
| status                    | ACTIVE                                                                                                                                                           |
| subnets                   |                                                                                                                                                                  |
| tags                      |                                                                                                                                                                  |
| updated_at                | 2020-05-16T13:33:53Z                                                                                                                                             |
+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```